# What does True in range mean in Python? Like "for i in range(0, True)" mean?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range

`for i in range(0, True): print(i)`

The output here is 0

But when I do this ->

```
for i in range(0, True):
    print(i)
```

The output shows nothing

**Can someone please explain whats going on behind the scenes in Python here?**

Comment: `True` evaluates to `1` ... `int(True) == 1`

Answer (score 1):

`True` is really just another name for `1`, because `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

`range(0, True)` is the same as `range(0, 1)`, which yields the value `0`. Your loop *should* output a single line, in contrast to your claim.

Your second loop outputs nothing, though, because it doesn't actually run; it's an indentation error.

Answer (score 0):

Few sample outputs to explain it's usage:

Example-1:

```
for i in range(0, True):
    print(i)

Output:
0
```

Example-2:

```
for i in range(2, True):
    print(i)

Output:
<No Result>
```

Example-3:

```
for i in range(-2, True):
    print(i)

Output:
-2
-1
0
```